# Scripting Help to filter out an IP-address

Tags: command-line, scripts, ip-address

I have a large text file that i want to extract lines of data from, i want to extract every line that contains an IP address that i can specify (z.z.z.z)

```
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local3.Info x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:19:52  y.y.y.y 00:05:06:17 , C8:D7:19:61:D1:9B DHCP REQ: Valid IP->Valid IP
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local3.Info x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:32:56  y.y.y.y 00:0D:8A:80 , 48:F8:B3:54:43:EB DHCP REQ: Valid IP->Valid IP
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local5.Notice   x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:32:56  z.z.z.z BTS Sending CDR: 067,H,00:F0:3A:99,00:0D:8A:80,48:F8:B3:54:43:EB,z.z.z.z,10780,906
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local3.Info x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:32:56  y.y.y.y 00:0D:8A:80 , 48:F8:B3:54:43:EB DHCP ACK: Valid IP->Valid IP: y.y.y.y
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local5.Notice   x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:00:11  z.z.z.z AAA: Modulation Change to 16QAM recvd from 00:16:C4:ED
```

So the output in the new file would look like this

```
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local5.Notice   x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:32:56  z.z.z.z BTS Sending CDR: 067,H,00:F0:3A:99,00:0D:8A:80,48:F8:B3:54:43:EB,z.z.z.z,10780,906
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local5.Notice   x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:00:11  z.z.z.z AAA: Modulation Change to 16QAM recvd from 00:16:C4:ED
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `grep`

```
grep -F 'z.z.z.z' logfile > results
```

The `-F` (`--fixed-strings`) argument prevents the period separators from being interpreted using regular expression syntax (which would match 'any character') but rather as literal periods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep or awk.

```
grep 'z.z.z.z' your_file
```

awk has more options

```
awk '/z.z.z.z/ {print}' your_file
```

but awk can do more formatting and has more options

see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-awk-language-to-manipulate-text-in-linux

and

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

for details

Tons of other options, perl would work too ...

Answer (score 1):

Anyone missed `sed`? Here you go:

```
sed -i.bak '/z\.z\.z\.z/!d' file.txt
```

The original file will be backed up as "file.txt.bak" and the modified file will be "file.txt". If you don't want to back up the original file:

```
sed -i '/z\.z\.z\.z/!d' file.txt
```

If you just want to print the output rather than save it:

```
sed '/z\.z\.z\.z/!d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl alternative:

```
$ perl -lane 'print if /z.z.z.z/'  < input.txt                                                                               
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local5.Notice   x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:32:56  z.z.z.z BTS Sending CDR: 067,H,00:F0:3A:99,00:0D:8A:80,48:F8:B3:54:43:EB,z.z.z.z,10780,906
2015-02-26 00:00:00 Local5.Notice   x.x.x.x Feb 26 05:00:11  z.z.z.z AAA: Modulation Change to 16QAM recvd from 00:16:C4:ED
```